# Binding Selected Item in a Listbox of Items to a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, windows-phone

I have a listbox which is bound to a list of Currencies items. Currency is a class

```
public class Currency
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string countryName { get; set; }
    public string imgUrl { get; set; }
    public string infoLink { get; set;}  }
}
```

A list box is bound to a list of Currencies Objects and each item in this listbox is a stackpanel of an image and textblock

I want to bind the SelectedItem property to a property in the Code-behind to keep up

```
<ListBox Name="sCurrencyLB" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="180" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=LiveTilesToggleBtn}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding STileCurrency, Mode=TwoWay, 
            Source={StaticResource livetilemanager}}"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding SCurrencyList}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <TextBlock Name="scountryNametb" Width="50" Text="{Binding code}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding imgUrl}" Height="50" Width="50" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code of the property that should beind the selected item in the listbox

```
private Currency sTileCurrency;

public Currency STileCurrency
{
    get
    {
        return appSettings.GetValueorDefault<Currency>("STileCurrency", null);
    }
    set
    {
        if (appSettings.AddOrUpdateValue("STileCurrency", value))
        {
            settings.Save();
        }

    }
}
```

Note : I created an instance of Class containing the property inside XAML

Answer (score 0):

Follow MVVM Pattern(pretty) that's what you need

try this:

befor **InitializeComponent();** in your contractor of window add this:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

so bind the **SelectedItem** like this

```
SelectedItem="{Binding STileCurrency,Mode=TwoWay}
```

Comment: I tried all that but in vain ! It doesn't select anything ! I'm trying to bind SelectedIndex but it gives an exception

Comment: I'm sure that works; Downlaod this 2 files and compare with yourself, I binded the ItemsSource, SelectedIndex and SelectedValue of listbox. download and if it works, you yourself leave a post and write the answer otherwise you can ask me again. [Download Here](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g0b2411915e0299fd99935218976c684a6acbab46c) , this files will be Expired after 7 days.

Comment: First I want to thank you for your efforts.
Let me clarify something , although this seems wired , the SelectedIndex in Windows Phone is a bit different from WPF.

Your code in WPF is working well but is giving an exception in Windows Phone. Fortunately , I found a solution which is to set ItemSource from Codebehind part not from XAML.

For the SelectedItem property it doesn't highlight the selected item although the binding works well.

Comment: O I see; I don't know the differences between WPF and Windows-Phone, Because i never work and never Research on Windows-Phone; so I can't help you more on this; I Wish you solve your problem. but If you have any problem on WPF, Do not hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work if livetilemanager here:

```
Source={StaticResource livetilemanager}}
```

Has a property on it:

```
SCurrencyList
```

Does it? If SCurrencyList is a property in your code-behind - since the code-behind is the default DataContext - you do not need to specify a Source for you SelectedItem binding.

By the way to see binding errors keep an eye on the Debug Window in VS while debugging.

Incidentally in C# it typical to name properties with capital first letter, e.g.:

```
public string Code {get;set;}
```